# Google App Script Help to call difference between two timed events

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Script for my Middle School that will allow students to sign out and sign in when leaving the classroom. I believe I have most of it coded correctly, except for  determining the difference between two times. Every time the script is executed I do get a time back, but it is always increased from what it should be.

Example:
Leaving at 11/16/2021 07:22:25 P
Returning at 11/16/2021 07:25:18 P
Time Gone 0.05

Example:
Leaving at 11/16/2021 07:24:59 P
Returning at 11/16/2021 07:38:16 P
Time Gone 0.22

I am not an experienced coder by any means so I am sure I am missing something in my program. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

````
 
 //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
 //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
 var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

 //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
 var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();

 for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
 {
   // CHECK CLOCK IN
   if(mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
   {
     Browser.msgBox('Need to Clock Out before Clocking IN');
     return;
   }
 }
 
 // ADD CLOCK IN RECORD
 mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue()).setFontSize(12);
 mainSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
     
 
 if (mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() ==  mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
   {
     Browser.msgBox('Your Time is Recorded, \n Please Remember to Sign Back In When You Return');
     return;
   }
 
}


function clockOut() {
 
 //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
 //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
 var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

 //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
 var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
 
 var foundRecord = false;

 for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
 {
   // FIND CLOCK IN RECORD
   if(mainSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValue() ==  mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue() && mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() == '')
   {
     // UPDATE CLOCK IN RECORD
     mainSheet.getRange(j,3).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);
     var totalTime = (mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() - mainSheet.getRange(j,2).getValue()) /(60*60*1000);
     mainSheet.getRange(j,4).setValue(totalTime.toFixed(2)).setNumberFormat("#0.00").setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontSize(12);  
     foundRecord = true;     
   }
   
 }
 
 // IF NO CLOCK IN RECORD
 if(foundRecord == false)
 {
   Browser.msgBox('Need to Clock In First');
   return;
 }
 
 // CALL TOTAL HOURS
 TotalHours();
 
}

function TotalHours()
{
 
 //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
 //DEFINE MAIN SHEET          
 var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATASHEET");

 //LAST ROW ON MAIN SHEET
 var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
 
 //DEFINE ARRAY
 var totals = [];
 
 //LOOP THROUGH ALL RATES
 for (var j = 5; j <= lastRow; j++)
 {
   var rate = mainSheet.getRange(j, 4).getValue();
   var name = mainSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue();
   var foundRecord = false;
   
   for(var i = 0; i < totals.length; i++)
   {
      //FOUND RECORD ADD TO TOTAL
      if(name == totals[i][0] && rate != '')
      {         
        totals[i][2] =  totals[i][2] + rate;
        foundRecord = true;
      }
   }
   
   //ADD NEW RECORD, EXISTING RECORD NOT FOUND
   if(foundRecord == false && rate != '')
   {
     totals.push([name, rate]);
   }
   
 }
 
 //CLEAR DATA
 mainSheet.getRange("F5:G1000").clear();
 
 //DISPLAY TOTALS
 for(var i = 0; i < totals.length; i++)
 {
   mainSheet.getRange(5+i,6).setValue(totals[i][0]).setFontSize(12);
   mainSheet.getRange(5+i,7).setValue(totals[i][2]).setFontSize(12);  
 } 

}```
      


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJBj7.png
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your script and your 2 samples of `Example:`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I am running a script on another sheet that when a button is pressed the script is run. It will collect the data in a cell which contains the a students name. This information is logged on another sheet which contains their name, the time they left the classroom and the time they returned. Everything seems to work fine except for the timed event. Name  Leaving Classroom Returned to Classroom Minutes
Joseph  11/16/2021 07:22:25 P 11/16/2021 07:25:18 P 0.05
Rosario  11/16/2021 07:24:59 P 11/16/2021 07:38:16 P 0.22

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. From your replying, unfortunately, I cannot still understand the relationship between your script and your 2 samples of `Example:`. Can you explain the detail of the relationship between your script and your 2 samples of `Example:`? By this, I would like to try to understand your question. For example, in order to correctly understand it, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue? Also, by this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Sure here is the sheet which contains the MAIN Students and DATASHEET at the bottom  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VbP48JLDSzBue65-yY3IpLDDSww-lN7NYvzN8ZTCHEQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing it. Unfortunately, I cannot open it. I apologize for this. Could you please confirm it again?

Comment: Try this link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR36FnMTbJV4Nl8X8x_VyG107Y8Q-oCSgfG3ITEvaMjSraMv-bUH2u4FuWSE74Qg1gCrO5bg12pvawe/pubhtml

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could see your sample Spreadsheet. In your situation, when it's `Leaving at 11/16/2021 07:22:25 P Returning at 11/16/2021 07:25:18 P` and `11/16/2021 07:24:59 P Returning at 11/16/2021 07:38:16 P`, what values do you want to retrieve?

Comment: The time between leaving and returning Leaving at 11/16/2021 07:22:25 P Returning at 11/16/2021 07:25:18 P this should return a result of 0.03 for 3 minutes, but it is returning a value 0.05 as in 5 minutes

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about the value of `0.03` and `0.05`. I apologize for this. For example, if those are 12 minutes and 123 minutes, what values do you want to retrieve?

Comment: If Joseph left at 7:22.25 P this would mean 7:22 pm and then returned at 7:25:18 P this would mean 7:25 pm. So if he left at 7:22 and returned at 7:25 the result should be 3 minutes or in my spreadsheets case 0.03. However, it returns a value of 0.05 which represents 5 minutes

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, how about the following modification? Please modify the function `clockOut()` as follows.

#### From:

```
var totalTime = (mainSheet.getRange(j,3).getValue() - mainSheet.getRange(j,2).getValue()) /(60*60*1000);
```

#### To:

```
var totalTime = (mainSheet.getRange(j, 3).getValue() - mainSheet.getRange(j, 2).getValue()) / (60 * 1000 * 100);
```

or

```
var totalTime = (mainSheet.getRange(j, 3).getValue().getTime() - mainSheet.getRange(j, 2).getValue().getTime()) / (60 * 1000 * 100);
```

Comment: That may have worked! Going to run a few tests and see. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you confirm that Tanaike's answer is correct? Also, as an alternative you can use, `var totalTime = parseInt(Math.abs(end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (1000 * 60) % 60);`

Comment: The following answer Tanaike gave did work! `var totalTime = (mainSheet.getRange(j, 3).getValue() - mainSheet.getRange(j, 2).getValue()) / (60 * 1000 * 100);`